# How do I decode and encode JSON into a generic struct in Swift

Tags: json, swift, generics, codable

Say the JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "email": "123@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "email": "345@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "next_page": 2,
    "prev_page": null,
    "total_pages": 3,
    "total_count": 12
  }
}
```

sometime it could look like this

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "id": 6,
      "text": "hello"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "hi"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "next_page": 2,
    "prev_page": null,
    "total_pages": 3,
    "total_count": 12
  }
}
```

As you can see, the codingkey will change according to the object in the JSON. 
How do I parse this JSON into something that I can read and is dynamic, like:

```
struct GenericListModel<ListObject: Codable>: Codable {
    let list: [ListObject]
    let page: PaginationModel
}
```

Where I will create the **ListObject** separately e.g: **UserModel**.

I will then create the model:

```
GenericListModel<UserModel>(list: UserModel(id: 6, email: "123@gmail.com"), page: PaginationModel())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to tweak it a little but you can do something like this:

```
struct Metadata: Codable {
    // ...
}

struct User: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let email: String
}

struct Message: Codable {
    // ...
}

protocol ListKeyable: CodingKey {
    static var listKey: Self { get }
}

enum UserKeys: String, ListKeyable {
    case users

    static var listKey: UserKeys { .users }
}

enum MessageKeys: String, ListKeyable {
    case messages

    static var listKey: MessageKeys { .messages }
}

class PagedList<Element: Codable, ListKeys: ListKeyable>: Codable {

    enum MetaKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case meta
    }

    let list: [Element]
    let meta: Metadata

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container1 = encoder.container(keyedBy: ListKeys.self)
        var container2 = encoder.container(keyedBy: MetaKeys.self)
        try container1.encode(list, forKey: ListKeys.listKey)
        try container2.encode(meta, forKey: .meta)
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container1 = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ListKeys.self)
        let container2 = try decoder.container(keyedBy: MetaKeys.self)
        list = try container1.decode([Element].self, forKey: ListKeys.listKey)
        meta = try container2.decode(Metadata.self, forKey: .meta)
    }
}

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let list = try decoder.decode(PagedList<User, UserKeys>.self, from: users)
```